# REVOLUT business api payments failed between 2 accounts

Tags: api, payment, payment-processing

I have integrated the REVOLUT API for one of my customer (I'm using Windev)

Everything works fine (authorization, tokens renew, accounts and counterparties listing aso ...)

But I have one problem using the payment endpoint
I send this :

```
{
    "request_id": "TEST_20210105093124648",
    "account_id": "da68d3db-ea3a-4882-9495-30eec748d27d",
    "receiver": {
        "counterparty_id": "676d4b18-12c0-4da0-9f4a-a3e6cc9788cc",
        "account_id": "a496b5be-a7cb-4932-aaf7-6f0db1bb15ce"
    },
    "amount": 3,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "reference": "TEST TRANSFERT 20210105093124648",
    "schedule_for": "2021-01-05"
}
```

and I got the following error :

`{"message":"Required 'profile id' is missing","code":2101}`

The official REVOLUT API business reference doesn't mention that "profile id" field required !

Many web researches and tests to find how to compose a correct payload : no success ...
And no response through a message in Revolut community...

I'm stuck for 2 days and I don't see where to add this information (syntax, position in the payload ?)

If somebody has already experienced this kind of problem, could you post a sample of payload please ? Or any information concerning how to contact the developer/API support (if exists !)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this issue, the fix for me was to remove the "schedule_for" field from the payload.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).